# Changing content of a HTML element's 'title' attribute used for tooltip, using jquery or css

Tags: jquery, html, attributes, tooltip, title

I have the following html element:

```
<a href="#" id="pinterest" alt="PINTEREST">
  <img alt="PINTEREST" title="PINTEREST" src="image.png" class="icon">
</a>
```

I need to change the `title` attribute value from 'pinterest' to 'contact us', which is used as a tooltip when one hovers over the above img.

I've done some searching and I believe it cannot be done with CSS (except possibly with `:before` or `:after` pseudo-element?), so I'm now trying in jQuery.

My jQuery looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#pinterest img').attr( 'title', 'Contact Us' );
)};
```

But it's not working.

I notice my jQuery version is 1.11.3, if it's relevant (I learnt about `prop` for later versions)

Thank you.

Comment: Your `jquery` version shouldn't matter.. Could you please confirm there aren't any console errors?

Comment: It's a wordpress set up. I see developer tools>console shows the following:`SyntaxError: expected expression, got ')'[Learn More]`
`GET 
http://.../wp-content/themes/wp_oswad_market-child/images/media/bg-footer.jpg [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 1155ms]`
`JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1  jquery-migrate.min.js:2:542
This site appears to use a scroll-linked positioning effect. This may not work well with asynchronous panning; see https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Performance/ScrollLinkedEffects for further details and to join the discussion on related tools and features!`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It was that I swopped the curly brace with bracket, as you can see with answer marked below. But interestingly, I don't see the console giving an error on this.

Comment: The above error you pasted is from `console` which means you had that error in `console`.. I caught this while preparing `Demo` for you, but I was thinking that you missed the part while copy pasting the code.. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem in you `jQuery(document).ready function` as you added curly after closing parenthesis

e.g.

`document.ready` function ends with `)};` while should be ended with `});`

Just replace:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#pinterest img').attr( 'title', 'Contact Us' );
)};
```

should be replaced with

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#pinterest img').attr( 'title', 'Contact Us' );
});
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#pinterest img').attr( 'title', 'Contact Us' );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="pinterest" alt="PINTEREST">
  <img alt="PINTEREST" title="PINTEREST" src="image.png" class="icon">
</a>
```

Note: there is nothing to do with the JQuery library version :)

Comment: Your `document.ready` function ends with `)};` while should be ended with `});`. Is this make sense??

Comment: Oh man! Why is it the simple things we overlook haha. Thank you very much. That is something I didn't check. It works now!